# WinAPI and programs in startup locations disabled by user

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, startup, boot

In Windows all programs added to startup locations shown in the **Task manager -> Startup**. User can disable any of that programs using TaskManager - but in this case Windows do not remove corresponding registry record or shortcut from the startup folder. Seems that Windows has its own list of 'disabled' programs.

Can we access/edit this list programmatically via WinAPI?

Comment: I hope you're not asking so you can un-disable your own program, btw.

Comment: Some useful information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/746414/1460794).

Comment: @immibis Nope. I believe that Windows protects list of 'disabled' programs from editing. But it would be useful to check that my program disabled by the user.

Comment: @flatmouse I see the list of possible `startup locations` for the shortcut to a program. But I do not see any info about programs 'disabled' by the user.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the SysInternals tool AutoRuns (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and read up on where it reads all of the settings.

Comment: @1001010: To my knowledge, AutoRuns does not display, which applications are disabled. This question is not about finding out, which applications should run at startup. The question is about those startup applications, that a user opted to disable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29994809/2604492

Comment: @Paul Wow, thank you. I will check this and post the results later

Comment: @Paul Yes, that is it. `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StartupApproved\Run` contain records with binary data for disabled programs. But seems that different versions of Windows have different binary flags for disabled programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StartupApp‌​roved\Run` contains records with binary data for disabled programs.
This data accessed and edited via regular WinAPI calls.